# can not run js file with nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, nodemon, powershell-cmdlet

I install nodemon from npm in project but cant run js file with 'nodemon run start' and facing this error:
nodemon : The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `nodemon` globally using the `-g` option.

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

This will add nodemon to your `PATH` environment variable so that your terminal knows where the executable file for nodemon is.

Otherwise your terminal doesn't know which executable you're trying to run.

Your second option is to run it through `npx`.

Use the following:

```
npx nodemon {filename}
```

npm will handle locating and running the executable for you. The `npx` command is installed on your computer by default when you install `npm`.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to install  nodemon if you haven't already

for dev environment run
$ npm install --save-dev

to install nodemon globally run

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

to run your app/server use

```
nodemon app
```

If the name of your entry file is not app use its name in the command

```
nodemon {filename}
```